# Как в исходящих смс различать, с какой сим-карты они уходили?

Tags: android

Добрый день!
Прошу помочь с таким вопросом, мне надо выгрузить все исходящие смс и отметить, с какой сим-карты они уходили. Делаю так:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/sent/");
final Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
cursor.moveToFirst();
String type = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("type"));
while (cursor.moveToNext())
{
tvsim1.setText(tvsim1.getText()+"\n"+cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("body"))+" "+cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("address")));
}
```

Но как можно получить с курсора, с какой сим была отправка?
Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Официально Android не поддерживает больше одной симки. Прошивки для аппаратов с 2 и более симками допилены производителем таким образом, что они могут работать с неск. симками. Но как именно они допилены - одному Богу (и еще этим производителям) известно. Если вы даже и сможете выяснить, как они это сделали, то вам придется писать разную реализацию для каждого производителя (а возможно и каждого устройства) отдельно.
Если все же хотите лично в этом разочароваться, то вот что я смог найти:

https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&q=android+get+sms+list+dual+sim
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27878785/how-to-send-sms-from-dual-sim-phone
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19728178/how-to-make-submissions-sms-with-sim2-or-dual-sim
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5255147/dual-sim-card-android
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14517338/android-check-whether-the-phone-is-dual-sim/17499889#17499889

Comment: Кстати, можно решить следующим образом, посмотреть названия всех столбцов в курсоре и найти нужный, что-то вроде "simid" или "sim_id", на разных устройствах может по-разному называться, а потом из него брать данные для идентификации сим-карты. Но такое решение подойдет, если программа пишется под отдельное устройство, как в моем случае слава Богу. Спасибо!